# Google Cloud SDK: Unable to deploy due to missing entrypoint in app.yaml

Tags: java, google-app-engine

On June 30 2020, Google are closing down the Google App Engine SDK and tooling. I have been migrating my project to Java 11 and the Google Cloud SDK. The project I am working on is just made up of servlets. I am running into issues during deployment, with the final error showing:

> "GCLOUD: Error message: Failed to generate app command: failure to
>   generate application start command: missing entrypoint entry in
>   app.yaml."

Upon attempting to deploy, using: "mvn package appengine:deploy" the following output is produced:

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ hellokb3 ---
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:/C:/Users/Emperor/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar) to field java.util.Properties.defaults
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [hellokb3] in [C:\Users\Emperor\eclipse-workspace\hellokb3\target\hellokb3-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\Emperor\eclipse-workspace\hellokb3\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [11192 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\Emperor\eclipse-workspace\hellokb3\target\hellokb3-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO]
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:2.1.0:deploy (default-cli) @ hellokb3 ---
[INFO] Staging the application to: C:\Users\Emperor\eclipse-workspace\hellokb3\target\appengine-staging
[INFO] Detected App Engine app.yaml based application.
Oct 01, 2019 3:16:26 PM com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.GcloudRunner run
INFO: submitting command: C:\Users\Emperor\AppData\Local\google\ct4j-cloud-sdk\LATEST\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud.cmd app deploy --version 1 --project kbnetworld
[INFO] GCLOUD: Services to deploy:
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD: descriptor:      [C:\Users\Emperor\eclipse-workspace\hellokb3\target\appengine-staging\app.yaml]
[INFO] GCLOUD: source:          [C:\Users\Emperor\eclipse-workspace\hellokb3\target\appengine-staging]
[INFO] GCLOUD: target project:  [testworld]
[INFO] GCLOUD: target service:  [default]
[INFO] GCLOUD: target version:  [1]
[INFO] GCLOUD: target url:      [https://testworld.appspot.com]
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD: Beginning deployment of service [default]...
[INFO] GCLOUD: #============================================================#
[INFO] GCLOUD: #= Uploading 2 files to Google Cloud Storage                =#
[INFO] GCLOUD: #============================================================#
[INFO] GCLOUD: File upload done.
[INFO] GCLOUD: Updating service [default]...
[INFO] GCLOUD: .........................................................................................................................................................failed.
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build da851139-6c89-4065-93c0-0940580b6af8 status: FAILURE.
[INFO] GCLOUD: Error ID: 80D70A67.
[INFO] GCLOUD: Error type: InternalError.
[INFO] GCLOUD: Error message: Failed to generate app command: failure to generate application start command: missing entrypoint entry in app.yaml.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:09 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-01T15:17:16+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

A fat-jar is built, so it compiles fine. I have checked it and can see all the dependencies are included.

According to the documentation it is possible to deploy the application with the YAML configuration the runtime and any fatjars will be executed. However, the build is failing and stating the entrypoint in the yaml file must be added, despite this being an optional field in the documentation.

```
runtime: java11

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: this field is required, but ignored
```

I have configured my servlets in web.xml.

Has anyone experienced anything similar and can point me in the direction as to why the deployment is failing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding an explicit entrypoint config - maybe your app doesn't meet the requirements for the entrypoint to be automatically determined, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and solved it after watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qx_T6-EKkBE) video and changing my `app.yaml` to:

```
runtime: java11
instance_class: F4
entrypoint: java -noverify -jar clothfinder-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the problem could be related to this [public issue tracker comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/136845066#comment4), since there are some similar points and the approximation by deploying a hello world application could fit for you.

Check that the maven plugin requires to remove the appengine-web.xml file and replace it with an app.yaml file located at /src/main/appengine/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to upgrade your Cloud SDK to latest version [265.0.0](http://You%20may%20want%20to%20upgrade%20your%20Cloud%20SDK%20to%20latest%20version%20265.0.0.%20It%20adds%20support%20for). Specifically, for App Engine it added support for:

- deploying Java11 fatjar directly
- Class-Path entry dependent jars for deploying a Java11 fatjar

It is needed to comply with the requirement mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/java-differences#creating_an_appyaml_file) to skip entrypoint definition in the `app.yaml` file:

> No need for an entrypoint with single fatjar with correct manifest class-path entry.

To upgrade to the newest Cloud SDK version, simply run:

```
gcloud components update
```